# Помогите разобраться с структурой микросервисов

Tags: rest, spring-boot, микросервисы

Технологии которые использую, spring boot, cloud, data. Написал микросервис book-service с rest api для взаимодействия который регается в eureka, сам service discovery (netflix eureka), и gateway service (zuul). Знаю что и для чего работает, но не понимаю через что с этим взаимодействовать, а именно html страницы должен отдавать gateway service после обращения к сервисам или же мне надо написать другое приложение (далее клиент) которое будет дёргать gateway service и отдавать то, что прислали МС и клиент уже мержит результат и формирует страницы?

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, наиболее актуальным в современном мире будет создание front-end части на JS фрэймворке.

Скорее всего, все будет выглядеть как-то так:

- front будет отправлять запросы в back
- back будет что-то делать и отвечать (либо сохранять результат)
- front будет получать (либо сам запрашивать) результат и отрисовывать html